# 〜といっている from Dragon Ball

Tags: translation, meaning, particle-と, particle-が, manga

Villain to Goku in Dragon Ball (Chapter 2), translated as: "If you leave the turtle, I'll spare your lives".

> かめをおいていけば = If you leave behind the turtle
>
> 命を助けてやる = I'll save your lives for you
>
> といってる = He is saying
>
> ん = nominalizer
>
> だが = however

I can't understand why the reported speech and why there's a だが at the end.

May be he is saying: "Although they say that" in a figurative way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a bit more context, he is saying

> ははー
> ボウズ！！
> その海【うみ】ガメ
> オレさまに
> よこさんか？
>
> [...]
>
> カメを
> おいていけば
> 命【いのち】を助けて【たすけて】やる**と**
> **いってるんだが**・・・
>
> まさか
> さからおうっ
> てんじゃ
> ないだろ？

So here といってる is used to cite his previous sentence (where he already asked them to hand over the turtle) and が is used with its usual meaning of "but" (and could for example be substituted by けど here).

So a semi-literal translation might be something like

> Hey, I'm saying I'll let you live if you hand over the turtle, but... you're not actually going to go against what I said, are you?

Comment: Thanks por taking all the trouble and look for it. I didn't know previous sentences were so important in this case. Now I perfectly understand what the villain says.